# Global (not locally defined) quantities in General relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, observables

So I was reading about center of mass (relativistic) on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass_(relativistic)#Group_theoretical_definition) and saw an interesting comment:

> Since the Poincaré generators depend on all the components of the
> isolated system even when they are at large space-like distances, this result shows that the relativistic collective variables are global (not locally defined) quantities. Therefore, all of them are
> non-measurable quantities, at least with local measurements.

Are there any list of global quantities in general relativity? I'm confused since I can't fathom even one in the language of differential geometry. Even a proof for the impossibility of such a quantity will suffice.

Comment: One example would be the gravitational energy, which is a non-local quantity in GR. Also there is this idea of relative twist b/w adjacent null rays which is non-local (but measurable) and independent of curvature of space-time. I'll have to verify other examples

Comment: Perhaps a better word would be non-local rather than global?

Comment: I think there is an ambiguity on how we define "non-local" or "global" quantities, it depends on the context. Like when I say gravitational energy is non-local: here non-local refers to the fact that gravitational energy is zero at every point but somehow appears in total energy contribution. Another example: consider how mass is defined in GR: it is a quasi-local quantity where a non-zero mass is evaluated by performing an integral over a closed space-like surface. Here we are integrating out non-zero contributions from every point. Similarly non-locality in relative twist have diff meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any list of global quantities in general relativity?

The type of global quantities that would serve as “collective variables” in general relativity is the “surface charges”.

[ADM formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) provides us with the prototypical examples of such quantities: ADM energy & momentum, ADM mass, ADM angular momentum and center of mass. These quantities possess some properties that would clarify their origin:

- they are defined not for all possible spacetimes but for a specific class of spacetimes (asymptotically flat) that satisfy boundary conditions imposed at *spacelike infinity*;
- they are evaluated as 2-surface integrals at spatial infinity on constant time slices;
- they are naturally organized in Poincaré covariant objects: ADM energy & momentum form a 4-vector (with ADM mass being the Lorentzian norm of it), etc.

This illustrates the general idea behind surface charges: first, we have boundary conditions that are sufficiently lax to allow for some *nontrivial diffeomorphisms* acting on the boundary data. This lets us define *asymptotic symmetry group* and formulate a lower dimensional conservation law at the boundary and find corresponding conserved quantities: surface charges.

In the case of ADM formalism, the asymptotic symmetry group is just the Poincaré group, so the conserved quantities have natural interpretation of energy, momentum & angular momentum, but of course there could be other types of boundary conditions. For example, the group of asymptotic symmetries  acting on null infinities of asymptotically flat spacetimes is the [BMS group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondi%E2%80%93Metzner%E2%80%93Sachs_group) which in turn leads to *BMS charges*.

For a detailed discussion of surface charges in general relativity see the book:

- Compère, G. (2019). *Advanced lectures on general relativity* (Vol. 952). Springer, also available as  [arXiv:1801.07064](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07064), Ch. 1.

Summary of ADM formalism from 1962:

- Arnowitt, R., Deser, S., & Misner, C. W. (2008). *Republication of: The dynamics of general relativity*. General Relativity and Gravitation, 40(9), 1997-2027, [doi:10.1007/s10714-008-0661-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10714-008-0661-1), [arXiv:gr-qc/0405109](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0405109).

Answer (score 1):

One example of a non-local quantity which is observable is a gravitational Wilson loop:

$$W(L)=\text{tr}\big(P\exp(i\oint_Ldx^{\mu}\Gamma_{\mu})\big)$$

Where $L$ is a closed loop, $P$ denotes path ordering (the same way it is defined for gauge theories) and $\Gamma_{\mu}$ is the affine connection (I'm suppressing the other indices to leave open the possibility of having a Wilson loop for various representations). This is invariant under general coordinate transformations, and so is an observable. I'm not entirely sure why such an object isn't discussed more in the literature, maybe someone can comment here why that is?

Comment: What does it "physically" correspond to?

Comment: @ziadh.muhammad physically is tells how some field changes as it traverses that loop. As you contract the loop to a point you'll arrive at the Riemann tensor at said point.

Comment: this seems more geometric than physical. how is parallel transporting a vector field at some point around a loop and measuring the difference caused by holonomy exactly physical. how is that measured with an experiment?

Comment: I would argue that geometric data is the same as physical data. Geometric data gives you information about the gravitational field. More explicitly, it's been proven that one can uniquely determine the connection (up to coordinate transformation) from the set of all Wilson loops.